# Como interpretar "+" como espaço na url?

Tags: javascript

Bem, tenho a página de pesquisa no meu site, e quando o formulário inicial pesquisa, você digita "stack overflow" como pesquisa, e na url fica stack+overflow em vez de stack%20overflow. Tem como interpretar "+" como "espaço" e + %2B como "+" utilizando javascript?

Comment: Você já tem a resposta, basta usar a função encodeURIComponent(); na ação de submit do seu form; http://jsfiddle.net/Wagner/xaheddrr/

Comment: Confirmando se entendi: você quer ler o valor da URL e converter os `+` de volta para espaços?

Comment: É estranho o resultado que você quer obter, mas, acredito que utilizando algo como : `//exemplo de url: "www.seudominio.com.br/busca.php?stack+overflow";
var parametroDeBusca = location.search.substring(1);
parametroDeBusca.replace('+', ' ');` funcione

Comment: Se o que ele quer é na hora da "leitura" , então o problema não é uma questão de javascript, mas sim de server-side (resposta do servidor). Gustavo por favor reformule a questão para podermos ter certeza qual a sua necessidade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar `window.location` combinado com `encodeURIComponent`

**Exemplo com `window.location`**:

```
<form id="search-form" action="" method="GET">
<input type="text" id="search-box">
<input type="submit" value="buscar">
</form>
<script>
    (function() {
        var searchForm = document.getElementById("search-form");
        var searchBox = document.getElementById("search-box");
        searchForm.onsubmit = function () {
            window.location = "busca?query=" + encodeURIComponent(searchBox.value);
            return false;//Isto previne o redirecionamento "nativo" do form
        };
    })();
</script>
```

**Exemplo com `alert` (para poder visualizar o resultado)**:

```js
var searchForm = document.getElementById("search-form");
var searchBox = document.getElementById("search-box");
searchForm.onsubmit = function () {
    alert(encodeURIComponent(searchBox.value));
    return false;//Isto previne o redirecionamento "nativo" do form
};
```

```html
<form id="search-form" action="" method="GET">
 <input type="text" value="a+b+c+d+e+f" id="search-box">
 <input type="submit" value="buscar">
</form>
```

> Note que [`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) é diferente de [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Comment: Não tem como usar o window.location, pois tenho um script de mudança do action do form para trocar o destino da pesquisa.

Comment: Então se existe alguma "dependência" em seu código você deveria ter adicionado o código inteiro na questão, pois se não a questão perde o foco, já que você não especificou isto. Edite a sua questão e adicione o código inteiro. Grato

Comment: Mas tem como na pagina de pesquisa converter "+" em espaço? Segue o exemplo do google: http://google.com/search?q=stack+overflow . Ele converte o + em espaço.

Comment: Mas quando se encodifica +, ele vira %2b, não %20, equivalente ao espaço.

Comment: com `encodeURI` sim `+` é um espaço, com `encodeURIComponent`, o `+` é considerado sinal de mais mesmo. Tente usar o exemplo que postei em um novo html sem o seu código. Leia a documentação: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI e https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent para entender as diferenças

Comment: Por favor o "downvoter" especifique o motivo do voto negativo, para que eu possa melhorar a resposta.

Comment: Não sei quem foi nem o motivo, mas tem gente que vota conta quando não acha a pergunta clara e a resposta é baseada numa suposição (neste caso, de que ele quer codificar a querystring antes de postar o form, e não reverter a codificação). Mas é só um chute, só o próprio downvoter poderia confirmar o motivo.

Comment: @bfavaretto obrigado, sim imagino que seja realmente algo do genero, em todas comunidades "stackexchange" existe tal situação, talvez seja medo de criar alguma "rixa", eu pessoalmente vejo o voto negativo como algo útil e não levo a mal, desde que eu seja capaz de entender aonde posso melhorar. Grato

Comment: Desculpe, mas não fui eu que votei negativo, pelo contrarário, dei um voto positivo e até aceitei sua resposta.

Comment: @GustavoBarbosa obrigado, eu não disse que foi você, só queria que "downvoter" disse-se qual a minha falha para eu poder melhorar a questão. Mudando de assunto, conseguiu realmente solucionar o seu problema? Abraços